# Невозможно определить формат uri

Tags: c#, fileupload, uri

Собственно, вот код -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation; 
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient ftp = new WebClient();
            ftp.BaseAddress = "ftp://files.000webhost.com";
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("kardlnal", "Tesak1488");
            Uri uri = new Uri("/mana");
            ftp.UploadFile(uri, "POST", @"C:\eula.1049.txt"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Все вроде нормально, но при компиляции вдруг выскакивает ошибка - невозможно определить формат uri. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Только не "при компиляции", а "в рантайме": при компиляции ошибок не вываливается.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у Uri пять перегрузок на конструкторе и вы взяли ту, которая принимает полный адрес, а не ту, которая принимает базовый адрес и относительный.

Правильно так:

```
var ftpUrl = new Uri("ftp://files.000webhost.com");
Uri uri = new Uri(ftpUrl, "/mana");
```

Comment: да, помогло, но теперь подчеркивается последняя строчка и пишется "Исключение во время запроса WebClient."

Comment: @kardinal Формально может быть какой-нибудь [ошибкой мисконфигурации сервера](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1), но вообще есть предположение, что вы указали /mana как каталог, а по документации это должно быть имя файла на сервере типа `/mana/eula.1049.txt`.

Comment: И ещё предположение: у вас стоит метод POST, но для FTP ведь используется CTOR, попробуйте заменить или убрать вовсе

Comment: У него уже задан base address у WebClient,  скорее всего хватило бы просто задать UriKind.Relative